# How to check if an user forgot to fill a form without isset() or empty()?

Tags: php, string, forms, isset

Lets say a website uses this form:
`...`
`<input type="text" name="Username">`
`...`

And then the user forgets to fill out their username.

But you have this if statement in your PHP code:
`...`
`$posted_username = $_POST['Username'];`
`if (isset($posted_username))`
`...`

This is the "problem" with `isset()`. It will return true. It will say that the variable is in fact set because `isset()` does return TRUE if the value is anything but `NULL`.

The PHP manual says that that `isset()` *"Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL. FALSE otherwise."*
But how do I check if the user just forgot to type in their username?

"You idiot! Just use `empty()`."
Well, what happens if the user wants to have "0" as their username?
It will say that the field was empty even when it was filled with "0".

So, what is a simple way to check if an user forgot to fill out a form? An user should be able to have "0" as their username.

Comment: `if (strlen($_POST['Username']) === 0) { ... }`

Comment: @iainn wow, can't believe I didn't think of that. Many thanks.

Comment: You probably want to also trim the entry before checking the length, unless it's okay for people to have whitespace usernames.

Comment: Or `if ($_POST['Username'] === '')`

Comment: why would you even let a user bear the username of 0 to start with? Plus, only "one" should bear that and nobody else. I don't think this is wise at all; use `empty()` and don't let integers only be entered in there but a string. There's always a better way to do things, and this isn't one of them.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Why wouldn't someone be allowed to have 0 as their username? And having unique usernames is already solved in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to test if the string length of the input is greater than zero, which can be done using PHP's [`strlen` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php):

```
if (strlen($_POST['Username']) === 0) {
  // User did not fill out the field
}
```

This will work the same if the field is missing from $_POST (i.e. is null), or has been skipped, but will work correctly for values that `empty()` would get wrong, like **0**.

If you also want to prevent users submitting usernames consisting of white-space (probably a good idea), then include a call to `trim()`:

```
if (strlen(trim($_POST['Username'])) === 0) {
  ...
}
```